# Bootstrap Program From Device to Memory

Tags: c, memory, operating-system, memory-address, bootloader

How can I start approaching a problem which asks me to write a C function to copy a bootstrap program from a device to memory?

I have access to these wrapper functions:

```
dev_read_byte(int dev_addr, char *mem_addr)

dev_write_byte(int addr, char *byte)
```

I'm also allowed to assume constants START ADDR and LOADER LEN are the initial address of the bootstrap program and its length in bytes

Can anyone refer me to where I might be able to find more information on how to approach this or what I should look for?

Comment: You will need to read LOADER_LEN bytes of data from a device and store those bytes into memory starting at START_ADDR. You have access to function that reads a single byte from a device and stores it into memory. Think about how you can create a loop in C to repeatedly read a single byte from the device and stores it into increasing memory locations, until you have read all the bytes.

Comment: there might be several piece of information missing from the problem ( like target address for example, which would depend on the architecture), although you might assume you would start from address 0.

Comment: @dvhh I had also wondered about this and now I'm told I can assume another constant START_MEM is available which is the predetermined memory address to place the bootstrap program in

Comment: @BrunoRijsman I see, I will give it some thought! So I need to loop over all the bytes of data, and store the bytes in incrementing locations in memory starting with the START_ADDR?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @BrunoRijsman am I looking for something like: `for(i=0; i<LOADER_LEN; i++){ my_byte = dev_read_byte(START_ADDR, START_MEM); START_ADDR += 1; dev_write_byte(START_ADDR, my_byte); }`